# vbscript skipline and cr line endings

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, filesystemobject

For some reason when I use the objFile.ReadLine method to read my text file, the entire file is returned as one long line. The file I'm opening is using CR line endings instead of CRLF or LF line endings. Does anyone know how I can read this file line by line in vbscript if ReadLine does not recognize CR line endings? Code is below:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set txsInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Path\To\My\File.csv",1)
'Read lines one by one 
Do While txsInput.AtEndOfStream <> True
  strTemp = txsInput.ReadLine
  msgbox strTemp
Loop
```

Instead of alerting for each line, I get one alert with the entire file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863400/asp-readline-non-standard-line-endings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ReadLine` won't work in your case, because it depends on the existence of a `vbLf` character. If you don't want to re-encode the line breaks you can do either what [Panayot Karabakalov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17181207/1630171) suggested (if the file is large), or read the entire file and split it at `vbCr` (if the file is not-so-large):

```
text = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Path\To\My\File.csv").ReadAll
For Each line In Split(text, vbCr)
  MsgBox line
Next
```

Re-encoding the file can be done like this:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

filename = "C:\path\to\your.csv"

Set infile  = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)
Set outfile = fso.OpenTextFile(filename & ".tmp", 2)

Do Until infile.AtEndOfStream
  c = infile.Read(1)
  If c = vbCr Then
    outfile.Write vbCrLf
  Else
    outfile.Write c
  End If
Loop

infile.Close
outfile.Close

fso.DeleteFile filename, True
fso.MoveFile filename & ".tmp", filename
```

Or you could use something like [`recode`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/recode.htm) for the conversion. Most text editors (e.g. [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html), [UltraEdit](http://www.ultraedit.com/), …) can do this kind of conversion, too.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up reading the whole file at once since the files won't be very large and then splitting it to count the number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best idea (and not tested) but try this one.

```
Do Until txsInput.AtEndOfStream
    strTemp = ""
    Do
        strChar = txsInput.Read(1)
        If strChar <> vbCr Then
            strTemp = strTemp & strChar
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    If Len(strTemp) Then MsgBox strTemp
Loop
```

Comment: I'd drop the `Else` branch and check the condition at the bottom of the loop: `Loop Until strChar = vbCr Or txsInput.AtEndOfStream`. It's cleaner than using `Exit Do`.